# Swap two strings in the same line starting with a specific character

Tags: bash, macos, awk, sed

I'm working with a file with multiple lines and I need to swap some blocks of strings in it.

Let's say I have this kind of structure:

```
# some comment
here is some text
f  483/1318/1298 484/1319/1299 485/1320/1300
f  486/1321/1301 485/1320/1300 484/1319/1299
f  64//59 67//62 76//71
v 1 2 3
```

I would like to swap only the last two blocks of string of the lines starting with the `f` character (note that after f there are 2 spaces).

So the result I would like to obtain is:

```
# some comment
here is some text
f  483/1318/1298 485/1320/1300 484/1319/1299
f  486/1321/1301 484/1319/1299 485/1320/1300
f  64//59 76//71 67//62 
v 1 2 3
```

What sed command (or any other) should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `sed` solution:

```
sed '/^f  /s/ \([^ ]*\)  *\([^ ]*\) *$/ \2 \1/' input
```

This modifies any line that begins with "f" and two spaces, swapping the last two fields, where fields are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` can do that pretty simply - `awk '$0~/^f/ {x=$4;$4=$3;$3=x;} 1' file`

`$0 ~ /^f/` executes the following block for only lines beginning with `f`.  $0 being the current line entirely.

`{x=$4;$4=$3;$3=x;}` is executed only for the matching lines and stores the 4th field (delimited by spaces) in a variable, then sets it to the 3rd field, then sets the 3rd to the variable.

`1` has awk print all lines, as awk's default behavior is `print` and the one is truthy.

```
$ cat file
# some comment
here is some text
f  483/1318/1298 484/1319/1299 485/1320/1300
f  486/1321/1301 485/1320/1300 484/1319/1299
f  64//59 67//62 76//71
v 1 2 3

$ awk '$0~/^f/ {x=$4;$4=$3;$3=x;} 1' file
# some comment
here is some text
f 483/1318/1298 485/1320/1300 484/1319/1299
f 486/1321/1301 484/1319/1299 485/1320/1300
f 64//59 76//71 67//62
v 1 2 3
```

Comment: You can short it some by change `$0~/^f/` to `/^f/` since it will teste the whole line as well.

Comment: this normalizes the spaces, so the initial two spaces are now reduced to one.  Not sure if it's a welcomed side effect.

Comment: is there a way to keep the 2 spaces? and also, how to change in place?

Answer (score 0):

In version 4 or later of `gawk` which provides the fourth argument to `split`:

```
awk '$1 == "f" {fieldcount=split($0, fields, / +/, seps); x=fields[3]; fields[3]=fields[4]; fields[4]=x; printf "%s", seps[0]; for (i=1; i<=fieldcount; i++) {printf "%s%s", fields[i], seps[i]}; printf "\n"} $1 != "f" {print}'
```

Broken out for readability:

```
awk '$1 == "f" {
        fieldcount = split($0, fields, / +/, seps); 
        x = fields[3]; 
        fields[3] = fields[4]; 
        fields[4] = x; 
        printf "%s", seps[0]; 
        for (i=1; i<=fieldcount; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", fields[i], seps[i]
        }; 
        printf "\n"
    } 
    $1 != "f" {print}'
```

This saves the field separators so they can be output as they were originally.

Comment: returned error:  `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 $1 == "f" {fieldcount=split($0, fields, / >>>  +/, <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Comment: @Blueko: What version of awk are you using? If it's not gawk 4 or later, then it won't work.

Comment: @Blueko: That's not "version 4 or later of `gawk`" so my answer won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^(f  .*) (\S+) (\S+) *$/\1 \3 \2/' file
```

Use pattern matching, grouping and back references.

Comment: @Blueko perhaps there is white space at the end of the line. See update.